# Oracle: Errors Creating A Table With A Foreign Key

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, create-table

I'm new to Oracle. I'm trying to create a table with a foreign key, but I keep getting the cryptic error message:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

for:

```
CREATE TABLE purchase_history
(
    PURCHASE_NUMBER       VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    CREDIT_ENABLED CHAR(1)     NOT NULL CHECK (CREDIT_ENABLED IN ('T','F')),
    CONSTRAINT fk_customers FORIEGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id)

);
```

I'm not seeing the missing parenthesis. I'm guessing something else is going on. I've Googled around on examples for creating tables with foreign keys. I found a couple of different styles for syntax and tried a few with no joy.

How do I need to change my statement above?

Thanks much

Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with:

```
FORIEGN -> FOREIGN
```

Comment: Argh!!.  So much for the golden rule of "i before e except after c". LOL.  Thanks much.

Comment: I try to avoid doing that kind of griping, but an error message about a misspelled keyword is kind of a boilerplate expectation.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Steve You missed out a crucial part at the end: "I before E, except after C, *when the sound is long E*". Though of course there are always exceptions (eg. seize).